# TableView didSelectAtIndexPath: Sliding Left to ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I use a tableViewController and second viewController to show more detail informations.
This works fine, but i like to use the another transition: The tableView should slide out to the left and the detail viewController should slide in from the right side.

I hope it 's only a setting, but i cant find it. This is the code i use at the moment:

```
ViewControllerDealDetail *thisDetailInformations =[[ViewControllerDealDetail alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
thisDetailInformations.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController: thisDetailInformations animated:YES];
```

Comment: do you want a navigationController like transition ?

Comment: yes, a transition like the navigationController

Comment: y dont u use navigationController then ? :)
Is there any reason to use presentmodalViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use navigation control

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view controller name animated:YES];
```